# I have a problem while installing opencv in m1 Mac

Tags: opencv, c++11

I have a problem while installing opencv in m1 Mac:

```
Undefined symbol: cv::Mat::Mat(int, int, int)
Undefined symbol: cv::Mat::~Mat()
Undefined symbol: cv::imshow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)
Undefined symbol: cv::waitKey(int)

Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I get this error when I try to run normal code with opencv:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main(){
    cv::Mat imMat(400,400, CV_8UC3);

    for(int y = 0 ; y < imMat.rows; y++){
        for(int x = 0 ; x < imMat.cols; x++){
            cv::Vec3b &p = imMat.at<cv::Vec3b>( y, x);
            p[0] = x;
            p[1] = y;
            p[2] = (int)((x+y)/2);
        }
    }
    imshow("openCVTest",imMat);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

To install OpenCV in Xcode through Homebrew, I followed these steps:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
brew update
brew install opencv
pkg-config --modversion opencv4
```

And finally I added the installation in Header Search Paths (Xcode) with c++ Language Dialect C++-11.